# Implementing Drawer Navigator in React Native

Tags: react-native

I want to implement a Drawer Navigation in my React Native application. The setup of my application is as follows:

1. I have Onboarding Screens which will be displayed once you open the application. then I will move to the 'Home' Screen.
2. I want the Drawer to only open on the Home Screen and not the onboardning Screens.

Here is my Code: **App.js**

````
``` import React, {useEffect} from 'react';

import { MainNavigation } from './src/navigation';
import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen'
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';


const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();


const App = ()=> {
 
  useEffect(() => {
    SplashScreen.hide();
}, []);

return (<MainNavigation/>);
}


export default App;
```
````

**MainNavigation.jsx** file

````
```import React from 'react'
import { OnboardingScreen } from '../screens';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { DrawerNavigator } from './DrawerNavigator';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export const MainNavigation = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='Onboarding'>
      <Stack.Screen name="Onboarding" options={{headerShown: false}} component={OnboardingScreen}/>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" options={{headerShown:"false"}} component={DrawerNavigator} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```
````

**DrawerNavigator.jsx** file

````
```import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { HomeScreen } from '../screens';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export const DrawerNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Home1" component={HomeScreen} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  )
}



const styles = StyleSheet.create({})
```
````

but i keep getting the error message

TypeError: Cannot read property 'MainNavigation' of undefined

This error is located at:
in App
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer
in CSR(RootComponent), js engine: hermes

How can I resolve this. and is my setup correct?

Answer (score 0):

You are not importing the Main Navigation component correctly. That is what this error is suggesting. I am guessing you have this in your navigation folder inside src folder. So it should be imported as:

import { MainNavigation } from './src/navigation/MainNavigation';